# installing npm in cpanel

Tags: node.js, npm, hosting, cpanel

This is the error message:

```
/home/hulukfyacom/nodevenv/myapp/10/bin/npm: fork: Cannot allocate memory
/home/hulukfyacom/nodevenv/myapp/10/bin/npm: line 13: /home/hulukfyacom/myapp/activate: No such file or directory
/home/hulukfyacom/nodevenv/myapp/10/bin/npm: line 14: /home/hulukfyacom/myapp/set_env_vars.py: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory '/lib/node_modules': Read-only file system
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/lib/package.json': Read-only file system
/home/hulukfyacom/nodevenv/myapp/10/bin/npm: line 35: /usr/bin/npm: No such file or directory
```

I am currently hosting my *nodejs* website and when I try to install npm it showed me this error. How can I solve this error please...any help...

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a symlink to your node and npm executables:

```
ln -s /opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs10/bin/npm /usr/local/sbin/npm
ln -s /opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs10/bin/node /usr/local/sbin/node
```

Not 100% sure if this is accurate since I don't have access to CPanel to test.

Although on further inpsection, it looks like you may be out of memory or even the file permissions are wrong. If the symlink does not work, can you run the following commands?

```
htop
```

If your memory is maxed out, this may be the source of your problem.

```
df -lh
```

This command will list the free hard disk space. Make sure the disk is not full.

```
ls -l
```

This will list the files and permissions, make sure that the file permissions are correct.

^These things are presuming that you have command line access. You should be able to check the resource usage from the CPanel interface if you need.

Comment: i have destroyed my app but still the physical memory usage says 524.46 MB/ 1GB .how to fix this using cpanel interface please?

Comment: Looks like memory usage is not maxed out. Have you created the symlinks with the first two commands? Run npm -v in the terminal and if you get an error, that is probably the issue. Sorry if I'm kind of spitballing but I don't have access to Cpanel ATM.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for! Cpanel said nodejs was already installed but npm command was not found!